# restrict the number of rows for a particular string in a data frame to some number n in R

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have a data frame(`data1`) whose structure is:

```
   Time-period   income
   Jan.2000      15000
   Jan.2000      23000
   Jan.2000      17400
   Jan.2000      11111
         .         .
         .         .
   Feb.2000      37000
   Feb.2001      39000
   Mar.2001      39000
   Mar.2001      39000
         .           .
         .           .
```

Thus for each month and year there are `n`entries in the data frame `data1`. **What I want is that for each month of each year there should be only atmost 2(top 2 if more than 2 are there) entries**. Thus for `Jan. 2000` I want to have only top 2 entries and remove rest of the entries from data frame `data1`. Similarly for every month of every year wherever there are more than two entries. How do I do that?

**UPDATE:** Here is my sample data set:

```
   Time-period   income
   Jan.2000      15000
   Jan.2000      23000
   Jan.2000      17400
   Feb.2000      37000
   Feb.2000      39000
   Mar.2000      39000
   Mar.2000      39000
   Mar.2000      39500
   Jan.2000      11111
   Apr.2000      39000
```

After filtering I should get:

```
       Time-period   income
       Jan.2000      15000
       Jan.2000      23000
       Feb.2000      37000
       Feb.2000      39000
       Mar.2000      39000
       Mar.2000      39000
       Apr.2000      39000
```

Notice that how last 2 entries of `Jan. 2000`(one of which is after Mar. 2000 so time-period is not ordered) and last entry of `Mar. 2000` got removed but for `Feb. 2000` and `Apr 2000` no deletion happened as there number of entries was <= 2

Comment: I'm guessing by top 2, you mean the two largests incomes. It would be more helpful if you could create a sample data set we can copy/paste into R and also explicitly give the desired output for that sample input in your question.  See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for tips and suggestions on how to do just that.

Comment: @MrFlick by top 2 I meant first 2 entries. The income column is of no importance for filtering. I have put a sample data in my post above.

Comment: You sample data is still a bit confusing. What class is your time-period column? Is it a character? date? factor? Is it properly ordered? Plus the space in the middle of the value makes it annoying to try to import into R. I'm guessing something like `do.call(rbind, by(dd, dd$Time.period, head ,2))` would work but you've made it difficult to test.

Comment: @MrFlick the `time-period` is of character type and it is not ordered.So entries for `Jan. 2000` are not together and may be spread out.

Comment: @MrFlick which space are you talking about? the data set is in update section in above post

Comment: The space in "Jan. 2000". When you using `read.table` on a value like that, R will interpret it as two columns but yet you've provided a single header without a space. It's just annoying to have to edit all the rows in order to be able to import the data into R to test different solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I apologize for that but this is the format in which data is present in my data frame. I will try to edit the post and manually delete the space for you.

Comment: @MrFlick I have deleted the space above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the sample data.frame

```
dd<-data.frame(Time.period = c("Jan.2000", "Jan.2000", "Jan.2000", 
"Feb.2000", "Feb.2000", "Mar.2000", "Mar.2000", "Mar.2000", "Jan.2000", 
"Apr.2000"), income = c(15000, 23000, 17400, 37000, 39000, 
39000, 39000, 39500, 11111, 39000))
```

You can run the code i suggested in the comments with a slight adjustment

```
do.call(rbind, by(dd, factor(dd$Time.period, levels=unique(dd$Time.period)),
    head ,2))
```

This will return

```
           Time.period income
Jan.2000.1    Jan.2000  15000
Jan.2000.2    Jan.2000  23000
Feb.2000.4    Feb.2000  37000
Feb.2000.5    Feb.2000  39000
Mar.2000.6    Mar.2000  39000
Mar.2000.7    Mar.2000  39000
Apr.2000      Apr.2000  39000
```

it does create odd row.names but you can get rid of those if you like with something like `rownames(x)<-NULL` depending on where you save the result.

Comment: is it possible to make this code not to reorder data based on `Time.period` alphabetically? what it does is reorder the entries so `Oct.1999` is coming after `Apr. 2000` but I do not want it to reorder. Actually my data starts from `Oct. 1999` and goes till `Dec. 2001` and I want this order not be changed

Comment: The code I posted here does not reorder. Can you provide a more representative sample data set. You said time.period was character right? Not a factor?

Comment: Sorry for the error.It's executing correctly. By mistake I had not put factor and hence it was reodering it. Thanks for help!

Comment: If you needed to re-order the factor again based on appearance of values, you could do `factor(dd$Time.period, levels=unique(as.character(dd$Time.period)))` in the code above.